# Windows 8.1 upgrade error 0xC1900101 - 0x20007

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

Trying to upgrade to Windows 8.1 from my 64 bit windows 8 pro system.

My System config is as below:

Processor: AMD a6 - 3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.40 Ghz | 64-bit, x64 based processor
RAM: 8.00 GB
Graphic Card: AMD Radeon HD 6470M 1 gb

I had daemon tools installed previously that I've **already removed**.
I don't have any USB devices connected, using my internet over wifi.

[Here](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s263/sh/95e1c372-053a-4f37-ac82-4cb30f4e0a2b/94906f0ab8451ba125906e827fe1fde3) is my Windows upgrade log.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. Look for 20th October Afternoon details in Log.

Thanks,
Sanket

Comment: Ensure that every connected peripheral (printers, phones, tablets, everything that isn't required to operate the computer) is unplugged and try the process again.

Comment: At what point did the error appear (after downloading, after installing, after restarting, after getting devices ready, transferring settings, etc., etc.)? Did a blue screen occur at any point?

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question. The link to Evernote might break and then the question doesn't make sense anymore. It is also much more time-consuming for people to answer your question if they have to visit external sites to understand it.

Comment: @Bob Once the 8.1 was downloaded it asked for restart. Then set up process begin and at the 75% it gave me that error. The pc gets shut down at that point. No blue screen.

Comment: Flyk I made sure that there are no devices connected.

@SanderSteffann Sorry for the inconvenience but putting complete windows log here wouldn't have been right either. Anyways what other details you need?

Comment: Sanket: I can't answer this question myself. Just trying to help you to improve your question and make it more likely you get answers :)

Comment: @SanderSteffann Alright. I appreciate it :) anyways if anywhere you'll come across the solution do let me know.

Comment: I tried uninstalling few of the external device drivers as well as virtual box. Then error was changed! instead of 76% the set up stopped i.e. pc was shutted down at 7% itself giving me error 0xc1900101-0x2000c

Below is error that I found in my update log

2013-10-25 01:31:55:760  496 1410 Report WER Report sent: 7.8.9200.16715 0xc1900101(0x2000c) 807050CF-9EC6-4235-8E96-019018A64F93 Install 101 Unmanaged

@Bob you got anything on this?

Comment: @Bob I've Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2012 and other development IDEs Eclipse, Android install. Do you think thats' affecting the installation? And yes I also have original Quick Heal Total Security = Installed too.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to upgrade. From what I could figure out by searching online, this has happened to systems upgrading from 8.1 Preview to 8.1 with a machine that is dual-booting Linux and Windows.

Is this the case with you as well? If yes, maybe the only way is to roll back to Windows 8, and then try again.
Another way you can do it is to replace GRUB2 with the stock Windows bootloader, and try again.

Comment: Vineet I neither had installed windows 8.1 preview (i've windows 8) nor do I have any dual-booting operating system. Although I've windows 7 installed in Virtual Box. So what you think about it?

I've already disabled Virtualization from Bios setup.

Comment: Yeah, even I removed GRUB and re-installed the windows bootloader; same error. I thought the AGENT_INSTALL_FAILED error was because of the bootloader.

Comment: Vineet I've got new error now.. just read my latest comment above. and let me know if you've any solution.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I'll try that tonight.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, then I updated a few drivers and disabled/removed some devices I don't use anymore.

I think Western Digital's `WD SES Device` driver was causing these problems for me, so I removed it and restarted the setup process and it worked like a charm.